# Submit test version on iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, app-store-connect

Maybe is not the more appropriate place where ask this question and in this case I apologize.

I've successfully submitted an app (v.0.1.0) on iTunesConnect -> **"Release This Version"** button is now available.

Before press it, I need to upload another version (say v.0.1.1) of same app just for let it test by a client.

Is it possibile without invalidating previous version?

I would to:

- keep (v.0.1.0) an (v.0.1.1) simultaneously on itunesConnect;
- "distribute" (v.0.1.1) for test;
- remove (v.0.1.1) later and, in case, release (v.0.1.0)

**I can't distribute (v.0.1.1) on Crashlytics.**

I've read **[apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html)** and my doubts are on "When builds become unavailable" paragraph.

Comment: you can move beta testing build to production regardless  of other version on ituneconnect

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Definitely you can upload next version for Testing without approval of current version.

Comment: can you explain how can I do it in your answer, please? Can I do through
Xcode as usually?

Answer (score 1):

Due to Apple has changed iTunes connect & made it more broader its very much easy to upload test builds. Its a great facility provided by the apple that we can have a multiple builds over iTunes Account under the app section & user can test the build & once testing done they can directly select that build in to App so it will be directly go for the App review.

So you can upload new test build any time whether current build is in review or rejected whatever status is. It will not affect the current live app. Also no need to invalidate the previous version.

Comment: are you sure? is there some documentation that confirms this?

Comment: yes, actually I have v.0.1.0 only in itunesconnect, waiting to be sure that is safe to load another version